# Strange line in nginx access log

Tags: nginx, http

I was looking through my Nginx (port 80) access log on a server which I do not use much, and I found a lot of lines that have an entire URL in the get statement. What is that supposed to accomplish? Most return a 404, but one of them (not the one below) was a 200, and had several Hexadecimal codes in the request right after it. What is going on?

```
#.#.#.# - - [28/Sep/2016:18:01:31 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using one of the ips of Chinese baidu service?
To be honest: if you're running server on public IP you'll have to get used to such entries. Treat them as stats and react if strange entries exceed some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You are scanned by somebody for open proxy...